# Django - objects.all() shows nothing

Tags: python, html, django, database, admin

I'm trying to get a list of objects in Django from a model.

I just want to get the list of 'dht node' from the request user, but it shows nothing in the html file (as if the list was empty). The user that I'm using has 2 'dht nodes' and they're shown in the django admin.

I don't know what is wrong, because if I use the instruction "member.dht.create(...)" in the views function and a create a new 'dht node' like this, this is shown. Only 'dht nodes' that I enter by form do not show. Can be the form?

Thanks a lot, Here's my code:

Models.py

```py
class Node(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, null=False, max_length= 50)
    description= models.CharField(default=None, null=False, max_length= 250)
    topic=models.CharField(default=None, null=False, max_length= 50, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class dht(Node):
    temp = models.IntegerField(default=None, null=True)
    hum = models.IntegerField(default=None, null=True)

class UserProfile(User):
    uid = models.CharField(default=None, null=False, max_length= 250)
    dht = models.ManyToManyField(dht, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Views.py -dht list-

```py
@login_required(login_url = '/web/login')
def listDhtSensor(request):
    member = request.user.userprofile
    list = member.dht.all()  
    return render(request, 'web/listDhtSensor.html', {'list':list})
```

Html -listDhtSensor.html-

```html
{% block content %}
  {% for dht in list %}
      {{ dht.name }}
      {{ dht.topic }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Forms.py

```py
class newDHTSensorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = dht
        field = ['name',
                'description',
                'topic',]
        labels = {'name': 'Name' ,
                    'description': 'Description',
                    'topic': 'Topic',}
        exclude = ['temp', 'hum']
```

Views.py -dht form-

```py
@login_required(login_url = '/web/login')
def newDHTSensor(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = newDHTSensorForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return redirect('/web/dhtDetail')
    else:
        form = newDHTSensorForm()
    return render(request, 'web/newDhtSensor.html', {'form': form})
```

Html -newDhtSensor.html-

```html
{% block content %}
<div class="boxReg">
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token  %}
  <h2>{{ form.name.errors.as_text }}</h2>
    <p><label for="id_name">Name:</label> <input class="barraForm" type="text" name="name" maxlength="150" autofocus="" required="" id="id_name"></p>
    <p><label for="id_description">Description:</label> <input class="barraForm"  type="text" name="description" maxlength="150" id="id_description"></p>
  <h2>{{ form.topic.errors.as_text }}</h2>
    <p><label for="id_topic">Topic:</label> <input class="barraForm"  type="text" name="topic" maxlength="254" id="id_topic"></p>
  <div class="boxButtonReg">
      <button class="buttonReg" type="submit">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shows nothing because you did *not* link you `dht` objects to that `UserProfile`, so if you later query for the `dht`s for that `UserProfile`, evidently the list is empty. You should add it to the `dht` relation, like:

```
@login_required(login_url = '/web/login')
def newDHTSensor(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = newDHTSensorForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save()
            request.user.userprofile.dht.add(post)
            return redirect('/web/dhtDetail')
    else:
        form = newDHTSensorForm()
    return render(request, 'web/newDhtSensor.html', {'form': form})
```

Note that you first need to save the `post`, so you should omit the `commit=False` aprameter.